# Android - Facebook SDK 4.0.0 - ShareDialog doesn't show when image sharing

Tags: android, facebook

I got a problem with using facebook SDK for sharing an image.
      I created a button which invoke native facebook app sharing dialog.
      But unfortunately, it doesn't show up. And the error message on DDMS:

"Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider798741073537656"

Please help to give some hint. Thank you!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.this);

    btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
            SharePhotoContent content  = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
            shareDialog.show(content);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you followed all the instructions? Generated the KeyHash, add the FacebookActivity and the provider in the manifest. Did you submit your app on Status & Review?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and what I was missing was the provider tag in AndroidManifest.xml. From the Facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#photos):

You also need to set up a ContentProvider in your AndroidManifest.xml where {APP_ID} is your app ID:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
      android:exported="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to figure out the problem. In my case the provider tag was outside the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml. Make sure you include the provider within the Application not outside hope this helps :)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        tools:replace="android:theme"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1533172037423618"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

First be sure you have mentioned the content provider in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
  android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
  android:exported="true"/>
```

1234 is you app id.

Second use a real device to test your application.And make sure you have installed the official Facebook application in your device.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the `<provider>` must be inside the `<application>` tags of the AndroidManifest.xml sdk

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on Glide v4.+

```
Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(YOUR_IMAGE_URL).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

            SharePhoto sharePhoto1 = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(resource)
                    .build();

            ShareContent shareContent = new ShareMediaContent.Builder()
                    .addMedium(sharePhoto1)
                    .build();

            new ShareDialog(getActivity()).show(shareContent, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
        }
    });
```

Code above will not work unless you add this in Manifest.xml:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
      android:exported="true"/>
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android